# ssh sqlplus command has $ symbol and it gets substituted

Tags: ssh, special-characters, oracle-database, sqlplus

I'm Running some SQLPLUS code over ssh.

```
ssh -q node1 'export ORACLE_SID=DB11D_1;ORAENV_ASK=NO;. oraenv >/dev/null 2>&1;sqlplus -s / as sysdba  << ENDSQL
whenever sqlerror exit 1
alter system set wallet open identified by "Passwo$1";
exit;
ENDSQL'
```

It looks like the $1 in the password "Passwo$1" gets substituted. And that's causing the command to fail.

The command ends up turning into
alter system set wallet open identified by "Passwo"
*

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-28353: failed to open wallet
```

Any idea how do I preserve the "$1" in the SQLPLUS command?

I have tried the below

```
- alter system set wallet open identified by \"Passwo$1\";
- alter system set wallet open identified by \\\"Passwo$1\\\";
- alter system set wallet open identified by '\""Passwo$1""\';
```

I cannot add an escape to the $ symbol in the password. So I can't do

```
- alter system set wallet open identified by "Passwo\$1";
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In the here-document that you pass to `sqlplus`, either escape the `$` as `\$` (it is unclear why you say that you can't do this in the question), or quote the whole here-document by using `<<'ENDSQL'` or `<<\ENDSQL` (this may be preferable if you have nothing else in the here-document that needs expanding).

Additionally, the string `Passwo$1` has to be single quoted in the here-document.  Since the document is a shell script, the string still has to be protected from the shell that interprets it.  You do this by writing it as `'Passwo$1'`.

Comment: Hi. Thanks.I have tried your solution. Hope I'd doing it right, as it still seems to substitute the $1 part of the password.

ssh -q node <<\END_SSH
export ORACLE_SID=DB11D_1;ORAENV_ASK=NO;. oraenv >/dev/null 2>&1;sqlplus -s / as sysdba  << ENDSQL
whenever sqlerror exit 1
alter system set wallet open identified by "Passwo$1";
exit;
ENDSQL
END_SSH

Comment: @ASanghvi I forgot to say that the string inside the here-document additionally needs to be single quoted, as it is shell code.  I will add this to the answer.